# PHP : 'use' inside of the class definition

Tags: php, oop, namespaces, multiple-inheritance

Recently I came across a class that uses `use` statement inside of the class definition.

Could someone explain what exactly does it do - as I can't find any information about it.

I understand that it might be a way of moving it away form a global scope of the given file, but does it perhaps allow the given class inherit from multiple parent classes as well - since `extends` only allows one parent class reference?

The example I saw was in the User model of the original installation of Laravel:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

}
```

and I've seen some examples of this model actually using methods included within the `UserTrait` class - hence my suspicion, but would really like to find out more about the meaning of the enclosed `use` statements.

[PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) says:

> The use keyword must be declared in the outermost scope of a file (the
>   global scope) or inside namespace declarations. This is because the
>   importing is done at compile time and not runtime, so it cannot be
>   block scoped. The following example will show an illegal use of the
>   use keyword:

followed by the example:

```
namespace Languages;

class Greenlandic
{
    use Languages\Danish;

    ...
}
```

which would indicate that it is an incorrect use of the `use` keyword - any clues?

Comment: If it can easily be answered then point me to that example -don't just downvote without actually giving the answer!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

Comment: So that's precisely what I thought - multiple inheritance - 'A Trait is intended to reduce some limitations of single inheritance by enabling a developer to reuse sets of methods freely in several independent classes living in different class hierarchies.' - was it really that hard? - oh - and thanks for the link!

Comment: It's really not multiple inheritance, it's closer to mixins.

Comment: Understood - although functionally it allows inheritance of additional methods - even with the similar overwriting mechanism.

Comment: The general term for this would be composition, or as Head First's Design Patterns puts it : "Instead of inheriting their behaviour, the [...] gets their behaviour by being composed with the right behaviour object.". Traits additionally gives you the advantage of providing you "direct access" to the functions which comes with the Traits.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

They are called **Traits** and are available since *PHP 5.4*. They are imported into another class or namespace using **use** keyword which is included since *PHP 5.0* like importing a regular class into another class. They are single inheritance. The primary reason for the implementation of traits is because of the limitation of single inheritance.

For more details see the [PHP trait manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php):

Comment: I'll accept this answer - although to be precise - they have been added to php from version 5.4.

Comment: How is putting "use" inside a class different than putting the same use statement outside the class, i.e. at the top of the file?